# Remove specific things from given line in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am having this below as an output

```
2017-04-10 12:23:00.307411 IP 124.108.16.209.443 > 192.168.180.3.44526: tcp 1209    
2017-04-10 12:23:00.836184 IP 192.168.180.3.43095 > www.facebook.com.443: tcp 303   
2017-04-10 12:23:09.948709 IP www.facebook.com.443 > 192.168.180.3.47172: tcp 38    
2017-04-10 12:23:09.986789 IP 192.168.180.31.47172 > www.facebook.com.443: tcp 0
```

and I want output like this,

```
2017-04-10 12:23:00 IP 192.168.180.3 > www.facebook.com   
2017-04-10 12:23:09 IP 192.168.180.31 > www.facebook.com
```

and importantly want to remove lines which starts with alphabets after **IP** word and also delete that line which do not starts with 192.168.180 after **IP** word, basically from above example I only want 2nd and 4th line as output.

Comment: What did you try for yourself?

Comment: Instead of _not these_ and _not those_, how about _get the ones I want_? `grep "IP 192.168.180" file`

Comment: I found nothing over google for above situation.

Comment: I didn't get you James Brown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to remove lines which starts with alphabets after ***IP*** word and also
>   delete that line which do not starts with ***192.168.180*** after ***IP*** word

***awk*** approach:

```
awk '$4!~/^[[:alpha:]]/ && $4~/^192\.168\.180/' file
```

---

space is a default field separator in ***awk***.

`$4!~/^[[:alpha:]]/`:
    `$4` - fourth field
    `!~` - not matches
    `/^[[:alpha:]]/` - regular expression, means "starts with alphabetic characters"

`&&` - boolean "and" operator.
***boolean1 && boolean2*** - True if both *boolean1* and *boolean2* are true.

`$4~/^192\.168\.180/` - matches a line if the fourth field starts with `192.168.180`

---

***Additional approach:***

To strip the unneeded parts of certain columns use the following approach:

```
awk -v p=".[^.]+$" '$4!~/^[[:alpha:]]/ && $4~/^192\.168\.180/
     {$7=$8="";for(i=2;i<=6;i+=2)gsub(p,"",$i);print}' file
```

The output:

```
2017-04-10 12:23:00 IP 192.168.180.3 > www.facebook.com  
2017-04-10 12:23:09 IP 192.168.180.31 > www.facebook.com
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, it helped me in removing lines. Can you explain me this command.

Comment: @VishalRabadiya, added explanation

Comment: @VishalRabadiya, do you need to strip this parts `.443: tcp 303` from the output?

Comment: Yes, Roman also want to strip 12:23:09.948709 after full stop i.e want to print 12:23:09

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141342/discussion-between-vishal-rabadiya-and-romanperekhrest).

Comment: Ya, thnx once again but also want to remove that .948709 from 12:23:09.948709. Please help me in this as well

Comment: Thank you very much @RomanPerekhrest you did lot for me. Thanx for your precious time

Answer (score 1):

*I - - want to remove lines which starts with alphabets after IP word and also* means (essentially) the same thing as keep lines which start with numerals and
*delete that line which do not starts with 192.168.180 after IP word* means to keep lines which have with `IP 192.168.180` in them and basically makes the first requirement obsolete. `man grep`:

```
DESCRIPTION
       grep searches the named input FILEs for lines containing a match to the
       given PATTERN. - - By default, grep prints the matching lines.
```

Try:

```
grep "IP 192.168.180" file
2017-04-10 12:23:00.836184 IP 192.168.180.3.43095 > www.facebook.com.443: tcp 303
2017-04-10 12:23:09.986789 IP 192.168.180.31.47172 > www.facebook.com.443: tcp 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try sed, something like this, it just syntax:

```
sed -e '/pattern here/ { N; d; }'
```

N and d are the command you can use.

This delete 1 lines after a pattern (including the line with the pattern):

*patter= your string*

```
sed -e '/pattern/,+1d' file.txt
```